# How Can I Use RDP as Client and Have Router Firewall

Tags: router, remote-desktop, firewall

I have a Motorola Arris SBG6782-AC router. This morning RDP stopped working (I use RDP as a client connecting to remote machines). Also ping wouldn't work for any address. In order to get RDP and ping to work I had to set the protection level to "Low" where all services are allowed. I didn't think the firewall would block RDP connections as a client, because a random client port would be bound on connection, like the HTTP servers do. Is there a way to allow my RDP connections and ping without turning off the firewall?

During this time the regular internet worked along with my chat app.

Comment: "This morning RDP stopped working" So what changed? Things don't just stop working all by themselves.

Comment: I have no idea. I'm assuming a router/modem update, but the management interface doesn't give me the last update date. Just a firmware rev of D30GW-EAGLE-1.5.3.0-GA-00-NOSH.

Comment: Is UPNP enabled in this router? It's broken in some firmware, and never releases port bindings. This is a classic symptom of older VZ actiontec routers, they bind/port-forward large port ranges (like 1 to 53225 tcp/udp) to local IP numbers via upnp, then reassign the local clients IP and never releases the port forward. The end result for whatever reason, seems to be that outgoing Nat starts to fail. (Untill you disable the firewall)